# Pass Value from Modal Directive to Controller

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a directive for signaturePad and i want to send the Signature Data to the controller once the signature is accepted by the user.

Here is the directive

```
.directive('signature', function ($ionicModal) {
    var canvas = null,
      ratio = 1.0;

    return {
      scope: {
        signature: '=ngModel'
      },
      link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, $controller) {
        $scope.signature = null;
        $scope.signaturePadModel = {};

        $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('modal.html', {
          animation: 'slide-in-up',
          scope: $scope,
        }).then(function(modal) {
          $scope.signatureModal = modal;
        });

        $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
          $scope.signatureModal.remove();
        });

        $scope.openSignatureModal = function () {
          $scope.signatureModal.show();
          canvas = angular.element($scope.signatureModal.modalEl).find('canvas')[0];

          $scope.signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas, {
            backgroundColor: '#FFF',
            minWidth: 1,
            maxWidth: 1.5,
            dotSize: 3,
            penColor: 'rgb(66, 133, 244)',
            onEnd: function () {
              $scope.signature = $scope.signaturePad.toDataURL();
            }
          });

          if ($scope.signature) {
            $scope.signaturePad.fromDataURL($scope.signature);
          }
          $scope.resizeCanvas();
        };

        $scope.resizeCanvas = function () {
          canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth * ratio;
          canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight * ratio;
          canvas.getContext('2d').scale(ratio, ratio);          
        };

        $scope.clear = function () {
          $scope.signaturePadModel.signatureConfirm = false;
          $scope.signaturePad.clear();
          $scope.signature = null;
        };

        $scope.save = function () {
          $scope.signaturePadModel = {};
          $scope.signatureModal.hide();
        };
      },
      require: 'ngModel',
      replace: true,
      restrict: 'A',
      templateUrl: 'signatureButton.html'
    };
  })
```

I am getting the signature inside the directive but how to pass that to the controller.

The value is coming inside $scope.signature.

Here is the codepen link
https://codepen.io/thesourav/pen/QWLVyjE

Comment: Looks like your codepen passes it to the controller fine. Am I missing something?

Comment: @codymikol i need to have it inside my controller scope which is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideal way can be to store that information in service and reuse it. But in this case, I have triggered the emit event and passing the signature once save function is called and catching the same in the controller and accessing the signature.
 Below snippet in directive

```
    $scope.save = function () {
      $scope.signaturePadModel = {};
      $scope.signatureModal.hide();
      $scope.$emit('c', $scope.signature);
    };
```

And catching the event in controller as below :

```
  $scope.$on('c', function (event, signature) {
      alert(signature);
  })
```

I have forked your codepen example([CodePen](https://codepen.io/rajatk_mishra/pen/mdbGryg)) and done the changes. Please test.